# Can nvidiafb and nouveau work together?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

Yesterday I posted a question detailing that my system was reacting badly to proprietary NVIDIA graphics drivers. Having now tried at least 5 different NVIDIA drivers (304, 340, 368, 375, 381 - I think, it's hard to keep track of them all) I'm beginning to shift my sights to only use the Nouveau drivers.

However, I noticed that a "`nvidiafb`" kernel is installed when using `lspci` to diagnose the drivers that were currently installed.

From what I gather Nouveau does not play well with proprietary NVIDIA drivers and the two cannot run simultaneously. As the resolution is currently locked to 640x480 within Nouveau I pose 2 questions:

1. What exactly is `nvidiafb`? I did not install this manually to the best of my knowledge.
2. Would `nvidiafb` have any impact on Nouveau's behaviour? If so, how do I uninstall the former to test this?

I see also that Nouveau actually had an update yesterday. It was suggested that this may have broken the compatibility with the display device. Therefore: is there anyway to revert to the previous version?

Operating System Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Graphics Card: NVIDIA GTX 670

I have been using Ubuntu for: 6 days (So I'm still very new!)

Answer (score 0):

nvidiafb looks to me like full-fledged hardware driver, so I do not believe you can run nvidiafb and nouveau at the same time.

nouveau provides it's own frame buffer.  For a more detailed discussion see [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/nvidia-framebuffer-support-needed-nvidia-geforce-gtx-760-a-4175599267/) at linuxquestions.org.

nouveau is a very capable driver(for 2d at least).  But the nvidiafb driver is very old, and may not support new cards well.  By the description in your post it appears you have the nvidiafb module loaded.

Since you used to run the Nvidia driver you might still have the nouveau driver blacklisted.  Edit your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file and erase the nouveau entry if it exists.

Remember you can run lsmod at any time to print out a list of your loaded kernel modules.

Good luck,

-Dave

Comment: Please use markup for the link

Comment: I believe that they can both be loaded at the same time, they would just represent two different RandR displays (also called screens). If you look at `man xrandr`, you will see that all of your outputs (monitors) are displaying parts of a single screen. The xrandr command makes it possible to change between displays / screens, but there is only ever one screen available in queries. This is because a display represents the mapping of a screen (the viewing area of all monitors) to a driver(called a "provider" in the X specs.) You can even change between drivers while running. To do this...

Answer (score 0):

if this question is can you have both installed on your system, the answer is yes. Fedora I believe installs nouveau by default and uses it as a fallback if the nvidia drivers fail to load (hence it's recommended to blacklist the nouveau module)

if the question is can both be in use at the same time, I don't believe that's possible, even in dual gpu setups, I could be wrong though.

if you want to have both installed and explicitly choose which drivers to use I'd recommend checking out this [entry in gentoo's wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_%26_nvidia-drivers_switching), it's super thorough and depending on what you are willing to compromise on, may help you find a way to use both on your system.